# Cofree objects and subobjects

Tags: category-theory, modules

In a category with cofree objects, are all objects necessarily subobjects of a cofree object?

Particularly, if the category of interest is a comodule category would this be true?

Comment: If you mean a category of coalgebras for a comonad, then yes.

Comment: I was thinking of a category of comodules for a coalgebra, I assume this to the the case, since cofree comodules are the same as cofree modules over an appropriate algebra, therefore they should satisy the same universal property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $U : \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ is a comonadic functor. Then every object in $\mathcal{C}$ is a subobject (indeed, regular subobject) of a cofree object. In particular this is true when $\mathcal{C}$ is the category of comodules for a coalgebra.

In more detail, let $A$ be a commutative ring, let $C$ be an $A$-coalgebra, and for an $A$-module $M$, let $H M = C \otimes_A M$. Then $H : \mathbf{Mod}(A) \to \mathbf{Comod}(C)$  is a right adjoint for the forgetful functor $U : \mathbf{Comod}(C) \to \mathbf{Mod}(A)$, and it can be shown that there is an equaliser diagram of the form
$$N \rightarrow H U N \rightrightarrows H U H U N$$
for each (left) $C$-comodule $N$. Thus $N$ is a subcomodule of the free comodule $H U N$. (The morphism $N \to H U N$ is precisely the co-action of $N$.)

Comment: I don't see why that should be true.